# Удалить все атрибуты из тега php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день,
Есть странички такого формата

```
<td class=x11111111111111111 width=140 style='>1111111111111111111111111111<td>11111111111111border-top:none;border-left:none; width:107pt'>
```

Задача превратить всю эту муть в тег `<td>`.
Т.е. убрать килобайты ненужного бреда из атрибутов внутри тегов.

Делать через strpos боюсь так как могу закопаться в разборе подстрок(жадности), так как внутри тега может быть в скобках "`<td class> </td>`" и другой бред. Т.е. внутри тега могут быть текстовые атрибуты, в которых могут быть подстроки соответствующие наименованию тега.

Comment: Убрать атрибуты нужно из какого-то конкретного тега на страничке?

Comment: у вас там два td, оставить один или два?

Answer (score 4):

```
$str="<td class=x11111111111111111 width=140 style='>1111111111111111111111111111<td>11111111111111border-top:none;border-left:none; width:107pt'> ";

print preg_replace('/<td(?:([\'"]).*?\1|.)*?>/',"<td>",$str);
```

Очистит теги  с учетом возможных включений в кавычках.

Для очистки любых тегов можно немного подредактировать выражение `preg_replace('/<(\w+)(?:([\'"]).*?\2|.)*?>/',"<$1>",$str);`

Comment: Поставил вам плюс за рабочее регулярное выражение

Answer (score 3):

Не думаю, что регулярные выражения в полной мере подходят для решения этой задачи.
Лучше воспользоваться [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php). Он корректно обработает даже невалидную верстку.

[Посмотреть пример работы](http://ideone.com/6QSrVo)

```
$string = "<td class=x11111111111111111 width=140 style='>1111111111111111111111111111<td>11111111111111border-top:none;border-left:none; width:107pt'>";

$doc = new DOMDocument(); 
$doc->loadHTML($string, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);    
// Измените селектор на тот, что вам нужен
$elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('td'); 

// Перебираем все элементы из выборки  
foreach ($elements as $element) {
    // Список атрибутов элемента
    $attributes = $element->attributes;
    // Перебираем атрибуты
    // После удаления элемента выполняется переиндексация списка атрибутов
    // Когда будет удален последний, условие станет ложным и произойдет выход из цикла
    while ($attributes->length) {
        // Удаляем атрибуты по одному, пока не будут удалены все из них
        $element->removeAttributeNode($attributes->item(0));
    }          
} 

echo $doc->saveHTML();
// <td></td>
```

**Обратите внимание на флаги** `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` **и** `LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD`.

Без них вывод был бы таким

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><td></td></body></html>
```

Начиная с версии PHP 5.4 и Libxml 2.6 в методе [`loadHTML`](http://php.net/manual/ru/domdocument.loadhtml.php) появился второй параметр `$option`, который поясняет Libxml, как следует парсить HTML

> LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED (integer)
>   Устанавливает флаг `HTML_PARSE_NOIMPLIED`, который отключает автоматическое добавление недостающих html/body... элементов.

> LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD (integer)
>   Устанавливает флаг `HTML_PARSE_NODEFDTD`, который предотвращает добавление стандартного doctype, если он не был найден.

Все предопределенные константы можно посмотреть в [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/libxml.constants.php).

### Внимание

Хотя в документации указано, что требуется Libxml версии 2.6, однако `LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD` доступен только с версии 2.7.8, а `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` с версии 2.7.7

Основано на ответах к вопросам:

- [Remove all attributes from DOMNode in a foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10281657/2486051)
- [How to saveHTML of DOMDocument without HTML wrapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22490902/2486051)

Answer (score 2):

Убрать всю муть [внутри тегов](http://ideone.com/0SxNXL):

```
$str = "<td class=x11111111111111111 width=140 style='>1111111111111111111111111111<td>11111111111111border-top:none;border-left:none; width:107pt'>";
$str = preg_replace('/<td.+?>/', '<td>', $str);

echo $str;
//result <td>1111111111111111111111111111<td>
```

Comment: А ничего что вот те '1111' были внутри атрибута style того тега <td> который собственно из всей этой строки

Comment: @Mike подлинно это неизвестно, может при формировании данного html лажа и произошла.

Comment: ТС в вопросе на это явно обратил внимание: "_внутри тега могут быть текстовые атрибуты, в которых могут быть подстроки соответствующие наименованию тега_"

Answer (score 1):

Универсальный клинер всех атрибутов какие только есть

```
$text = '<p style="padding:0px;"><strong style="padding:0;margin:0;">hello</strong></p>';

echo preg_replace("/<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(\/?)>/i",'<$1$2>', $text);

// <p><strong>hello</strong></p>
```

Comment: Смелое утверждение, учитывая, что на примере автора спотыкается: http://ideone.com/H77Iq9

Comment: Кроме того, в атрибутах допустимы не только цифры и буквы. Может встречаться еще, например, дефис. Взять хотя бы атрибут `data-*`. Да и не только дефис может быть...

Comment: по поводу data-* и прочего удаляется нормально , по поводу спотыкается не вижу прецедента , атрибуты удалены корректно , то что идет за тегом уже контент , закрывающего тега нет и вложенного тоже .

Comment: Это НЕ контент тега, это содержимое атрибута, поэтому нельзя сказать, что атрибут удален корректно. Удалено начало атрибута, а конец атрибута и его содержимое - нет. По поводу `data-*` и прочего вы правы. На ночь глядя я неверно регулярку прочитал.

Comment: `это содержимое атрибута` да точно , как то не заметил . Удаляет только валидные значения.

Comment: Значение валидное.  Присмотритесь. В качестве значения может быть любая строка с корректным экранированием. Тег в примере не закрытый -  только это невалидное.